# How to rollback database changes once error occur during insertion of bulk of records in Mule?

Tags: mysql, database, mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I have the following json file

```
[
    {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "Ramesh",
         "designation": "SE",
         "salary": 25000.00
    },
    {
         "id": 2,
         "name": "Anjali",
         "designation": "SE",
         "salary": 20000.00
    },
    {
         "id": 2,
         "name": "Harrish",
         "designation": "PM",
         "salary": 120000.00
    },
    {
         "id": 4,
         "name": "Rahul",
         "designation": "TA",
         "salary": 150000.00
    }
]
```

Here I want to insert either all the records or none of them. Means all the four records will be inserted to employee database or none of them above. But here you can see the third record have the duplicate id 2 as second record's id hold the same id and when I run the following mule application `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` error is occur but first 2 records got inserted into DB as error comes in records no 3. But here what I want is to prevent from insert of records or rollback changes if all records did not get inserted into DB (means any error comes in between).

**Below are my mule xml config file to insert json data into DB:**

```
<sub-flow name="insert-fulltime-employee-details-subflow">
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="35bfe913-8de7-4b3c-9ba9-98f375a2873e" doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/json"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
    id: payload01.id,
    name: payload01.name,
    designation: payload01.designation,
    salary: payload01.salary
})]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each">
            <db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database-Insert">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into fulltime_employee values (#[payload.id], #[payload.name], #[payload.designation], #[payload.salary])]]></db:parameterized-query>
            </db:insert>
        </foreach>
        <set-payload value="{&quot;message&quot;: &quot;All data successfully inserted into database&quot;}" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</sub-flow>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the block that has to be rolled back in the "Transactional scope". Like the below,

```
<transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" doc:name="Transactional">
<db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database-Insert">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into fulltime_employee values (#[payload.id], #[payload.name], #[payload.designation], #[payload.salary])]]></db:parameterized-query>
            </db:insert>
</transactional>
```

Comment: Transactional scope is not working for me. It can't prevent insertion of records if error(here primary key violation) occurs.